# Read content of folder without AIR in AS3 (no flash.filesystem)

Tags: file, actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a project and I need to dynamically check what is in onhe of my folder. The idea is that I have the id of a quest, and there is a folder name after that id. My code needs to check if this folder exist AND if there is something in it. After that, it show all the picture inside that folder. The goal is that I will just have to add picture in a folder to have them appear in my game.

I tried to find a way to check the content of my folder, but everyone say that I need flash.filesystem, BUT it means that I need to use AIR. AIR does NOT work in FireFox or any other browser.

Here is the website that make me understood that:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Photos_Graphics/Web_Graphics/Macromedia_Flash/Q_26118847.html

How can I explore the content of my folders then?

Comment: where are stored the folders? At your server or on local filesystem?

Comment: Folders on your server: A-OK. Local Filesystem of the User: Never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to explore the local file system without user interaction in Flash. If you want to do it, you *must* make an AIR application, which is not browser-based. This is a security feature that is imposed by each browser (you can't do it in JS either) and implemented identically by Adobe.

You can use `FileReference` to allow a user to select file(s) for Flash to have access to or save a file, but that is the most interaction with the filesystem that will be possible without opening AIR (which is also not limitless. Even with AIR, you won't have full access to the file system and will be locked out of certain directories and prevented from doing certain things)

Answer (score 0):

If the folders are on your server you'll need to rely on a server side script to do the job and pass the result to your app.
If you mean folders on client side computer it's not gonna be possible for security reason.